# Can't find symbol after importing package using Ssh tools

Tags: java

I am using the ssh tools for java and I keep getting an error after I have imported the package.  This code is from an example that comes with the packages.  I have added the library to the libraries of my project (netbeans) however I get a symbol not found on the first declaration of JSch, which I see in the package expansion, however I still get the error. Any ideas??

```
/* -*-mode:java; c-basic-offset:2; indent-tabs-mode:nil -*- */
import bin.src.com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Exec{
  public static void main(String[] arg){
    try{
      JSch jsch=new JSch();  

      String host=null;
      if(arg.length>0){
        host=arg[0];
      }
      else{
        host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                                         System.getProperty("user.name")+
                                         "@localhost"); 
      }
      String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
      host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);

      Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

      /*
      String xhost="127.0.0.1";
      int xport=0;
      String display=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter display name", 
                                                 xhost+":"+xport);
      xhost=display.substring(0, display.indexOf(':'));
      xport=Integer.parseInt(display.substring(display.indexOf(':')+1));
      session.setX11Host(xhost);
      session.setX11Port(xport+6000);
      */

      // username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
      UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
      session.setUserInfo(ui);
      session.connect();

      String command=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter command", 
                                                 "set|grep SSH");

      Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

      // X Forwarding
      // channel.setXForwarding(true);

      //channel.setInputStream(System.in);
      channel.setInputStream(null);

      //channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

      //FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("/tmp/stderr");
      //((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(fos);
      ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

      InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

      channel.connect();

      byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
      while(true){
        while(in.available()>0){
          int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
          if(i<0)break;
          System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
        }
        if(channel.isClosed()){
          System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
          break;
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
      }
      channel.disconnect();
      session.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive{
    public String getPassword(){ return passwd; }
    public boolean promptYesNo(String str){
      Object[] options={ "yes", "no" };
      int foo=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
             str,
             "Warning", 
             JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
             JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
             null, options, options[0]);
       return foo==0;
    }

    String passwd;
    JTextField passwordField=(JTextField)new JPasswordField(20);

    public String getPassphrase(){ return null; }
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message){ return true; }
    public boolean promptPassword(String message){
      Object[] ob={passwordField}; 
      int result=
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, message,
                                      JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        passwd=passwordField.getText();
        return true;
      }
      else{ 
        return false; 
      }
    }
    public void showMessage(String message){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }
    final GridBagConstraints gbc = 
      new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1,1,
                             GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                             GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                             new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0);
    private Container panel;
    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
                                              String name,
                                              String instruction,
                                              String[] prompt,
                                              boolean[] echo){
      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      panel.add(new JLabel(instruction), gbc);
      gbc.gridy++;

      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

      JTextField[] texts=new JTextField[prompt.length];
      for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        panel.add(new JLabel(prompt[i]),gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        if(echo[i]){
          texts[i]=new JTextField(20);
        }
        else{
          texts[i]=new JPasswordField(20);
        }
        panel.add(texts[i], gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
      }

      if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, 
                                       destination+": "+name,
                                       JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
         ==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
        String[] response=new String[prompt.length];
        for(int i=0; i<prompt.length; i++){
          response[i]=texts[i].getText();
        }
    return response;
      }
      else{
        return null;  // cancel
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also how have you added the package to your project? i.e. drag and drop or add through Java build path in project preferences etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `import com.jcraft.jsch.*` not `import bin.src.com.jcraft.jsch.*;` based on the code I see [here](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html).

Comment: I have it in a different location so I need the bin in front.

Comment: So you repackaged the jar file? I am not sure what you mean by it being in a different location. Did you manually copy this source file to your project source folder under a different package name instead of using the jar file?

Comment: the download doesn't come with a jar file its just a bunch of class files that I have compiled to .java files and created a .jar file with those folders, so basically created .java files and made a jar file of the com folder and then I went to my project and added a library.  and when I import that library I get a import unused error and the symbol is not found.

Comment: Well I am not sure where you downloaded it from. I just downloaded the jar file from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch.jar/0.1.44/jsch-0.1.44.jar/download and imports works fine. Can you please removing the jar that you built and use this one instead? And also do the import like I have it in the post. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: If you use maven then they have it in their maven repo too http://jsch.sourceforge.net/maven2/ .